# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for comparing pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` containing two pandas columns, one called `years` containing a list of years and the other called `line_items` containing numbers. A subset is as such

```
                  years          line_items
0          [2019, 2018]        [5709, 5795]
1          [2020, 2019]  [1759669, 1578624]
2          [2019, 2018]        [2019, 2018]
3          [2019, 2018]        [1487, 1314]
4                [2020]              [2020]
```

The reproducible df is pasted below:

```
df={'years': {0: ['2019', '2018'], 1: ['2020', '2019'], 2: ['2019', '2018'], 3: ['2019', '2018'], 4: ['2020']}, 'line_items': {0: ['5709', '5795'], 1: ['1759669', '1578624'], 2: ['2019', '2018'], 3: ['1487', '1314'], 4: ['2020']}}
```

What I am trying to do is remove any rows that contain duplicate values for both columns so in this case row 2 and row 4. My attempted solution was:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['years', 'line_items'])
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and create the Boolean masking for each rows where `years` is not equal to `line_item`, then use this Boolean masking to filter out the dataframe.

```py
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['years']!=x['line_items'], axis=1)]

          years          line_items
0  [2019, 2018]        [5709, 5795]
1  [2020, 2019]  [1759669, 1578624]
3  [2019, 2018]        [1487, 1314]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter/query

1.

```py
df[df.years != df.line_items]
```

2. 

```py
df.where(df.years != df.line_items).dropna()
```

3. 

```py
df.query('years != line_items')
```